# Does WinDBG purge cached pdb files after a while?

Tags: windbg

I use WinDBG a fair bit to debug dumps that testers send me.  Right now, I'm experiencing very poor performance with obtaining debugging symbols from Microsoft's symbol server.  I'm not the only one so I expect Microsoft are having server issues at the moment but it's highlighted something about WinDBG's symbol caching which I haven't paid much attention to before.

Very often when I open a new dump it's trying to download every pdb for all the Microsoft symbols.  It caches them for the duration of my debugging session, and if I close WinDBG and open it again it often opens without having to download symbols.  However if I open a dump that I was using a few days earlier it seems to have often lost the symbols that it downloaded previously.  It seems to be purging old pdb files or some such..

I have my symbol path set up like this:

```
SRV*C:\SymCache*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

So, question, is it possible to control how often WinDBG purges cached symbols?  I'd be quite happy for it to fill a few GB with symbol files since disk is cheap...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I've set symbol path in windbg, but why each time windbg downloads same symbol for same exe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39324154/ive-set-symbol-path-in-windbg-but-why-each-time-windbg-downloads-same-symbol-f)

Comment: I'm not convinced that is the same problem.  I've just opened several dumps that I opened last week and should have all the symbols for.  I caught WinDBG redownloading ntdll.pdb.  That's a symbol file which is always findable on the symbol server so I don't see why that should ever need redownloading if that version has ever been seen before.  I guess the only way I'll know for sure is to record the contents of my symbol cache folder and watch what it's doing over time.

Comment: Perhaps the community could set up a mirror server. If everybody contributes his locally cached symbols I guess we could get quite a good coverage

Comment: If you have some time, look into `.symopt-0x20000`. The description is a bit weird due to the inverse meaning

Comment: Windbg does not purge pdbs i have some pretty old vix 10 year old pds in my csche also if you are not aware you can dowload symbols and use it offline say with symchk   if windbg were to purge then old pdbs will be lost

Answer (score 2):

No, symbols are not purged. I am not aware of any information that would tell WinDbg the age of symbols except the timestamp which is not reliable. The file `pingme.txt` is an empty file.

As mentioned by @blabb in the comments, purging would be counter-productive, given that you can [download symbol packages (Microsoft)](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/download-symbols) for offline use for very old symbols, e.g. Windows XP.

On my PC which I got when I joined the company, the symbols of 2014 are still there:

[image: Symbols of 2014]

Comment: Hmm, you're right.  Mine do at least go right back to when I rebuilt my laptop a few months ago..  And yet I swear it's re-downloading pdbs I've used before..  I'll keep an eye on it and see if I can catch it out.